# Gradle exec task fails with "execCommand == null!"

Tags: gradle

I have the following task in my **build.gradle** file:

```java
task myTask(type:Exec) {
    def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    exec {
        commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'whoami'
        standardOutput = stdout;
    }
    println "Output: $stdout"
}
```

When I run my task with `./gradlew myTask`, I get the following output:

```
> Configure project :
Output: retrovius


> Task :myTask FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':myTask'.
> execCommand == null!

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

The task successfully outputs my username (retrovius), then fails anyway. Any pointers for what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Depending on what you want to achieve, the answer you found is probably still not correct.

All tasks have two main stages: configuration and execution. Everything you put in the outermost block to the task definition is part of the configuration. And the `exec` method actually executes the command whenever that block of code is evaluated. So when you type:

```
task myTask() {
    def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    exec {
        commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'whoami'
        standardOutput = stdout;
    }
    println "Output: $stdout"
}
```

Then it means you are running the `whoami` command no matter what task you specify. If you run `gradle -i help`, it will print the name. I expect this is not what you intend.

Most of the time, you will want to run a command only when the task is actually executed. So if you want the command to only run if you type `gradle -i myTask`, you will need to do defer it to the execution stage instead. There are two ways you can do that.

Either you can put everything in a `doLast` block like this:

```
task myTask() {
    doLast {
        def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
        exec {
            commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'whoami'
            standardOutput = stdout
        }
        println "Output: $stdout"
    }
}
```

Or you use the `Exec` *type*, like you already tried. The reason it didn't work for you is that you need to *configure* it with the command you like - and not actually *run* the command through the `exec` method. It could look like this:

```
task myTask(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'whoami'
    standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    doLast {
        println "Output: $standardOutput"
    }
}
```

You an also probably get rid of the `cmd /c` part. And `println` should only be used for debugging - use `logger.info` (or `.warn`, etc) if you need to output something to the user.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this. It accounts for why my `task help` prints even when people don't need help.

Answer (score 5):

I figured out that the only thing I was doing wrong was to include the `(type:Exec)` in the definition of my task. If I place the following code in my **build.gradle** file:

```java
task myTask() {
    def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    exec {
        commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'whoami'
        standardOutput = stdout;
    }
    println "Output: $stdout"
}
```

I get the following output:

```
> Configure project :
Output: retrovius


BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
```

My mistake must have been that I was defining the task to be of type exec, but not giving it a command to run. This reveals a fundamental misunderstanding of the exec task and task type on my part. If anyone knows more specifically what I did wrong, please feel free to comment and explain or post a better answer.